# Is optimization to avoid DSL downlink's speed degradation due to uplink saturation available in Linux deamons/drivers?

Tags: networking, router, modem, adsl, performance

In my PepLink Balance 300 router (lb300) there's an option called *DSL Optimization* with the following description:

> When a DSL circuit's uplink becomes
>   busy, it is a fact that the downlink
>   bandwidth is affected. Users cannot
>   download data in full speed until the
>   uplink becomes less congested. The DSL
>   Optimization could relieve such
>   problem. When it is enabled, the
>   download speed will be less affected
>   by upload traffic.

I'm curious if this kind of optimization is available also in linux deamons/drivers dealing with WAN connections of DSL type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux traffic control/shaping. This site is the definitive reference: http://lartc.org/howto/

Comment: Traffic shaping is not connected with any particular type of interface or protocol. I'm interested in this particular type of connection (DSL). From the description found in my router I guess the problem stems from the fact how DSL is designed. Or am I wrong and the problem is the same for any asynchronous connection where outgoing channel's bandwidth is needed to acknowledge data received?

Comment: It's not specific to DSL. Anytime one direction gets saturated it impacts performance in the other direction. Since the upload bandwidth of a typical DSL connection is typically much smaller than the download bandwidth, it's easier to saturate it and thus affect the download performance. The DSL Optimization feature of your router probably prioritizes the outbound TCP ACK packets over other outbound packets.